# Xamarin Forms User Control: Forward Entry.Behaviors dependency property in composite control

Tags: forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dependency-properties, behavior

I created a user control in which I placed an Xamarin.Forms Entry. The idea is to wrap the original Entry with some additional funtionality such as an input validation error, images, etc... and use the composite control all over my Xamarin.Forms app. Nothing special so far.

All relevant dependency properties of Entry are forwarded to the wrapping composite control, e.g. Text, Style. Now, the problem comes when I want to expose a dependency property for Behavoirs which I want to forward to the nested Entry control.

Does anyone have experience in “forwarding” nested dependency properties, in particular with Behaviors?

**Update 2018-11-25:**

ValidatableEntry.xaml is a Grid which contains the nested Entry control. Text and Placeholder properties of Entry are bound to local dependency properties, I call this approach "property forwarding".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="ValidatableEntry"
    x:Name="Control">

    <Entry 
        Grid.Row="0"
        x:Name="Entry"
        Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference Control}, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Placeholder="{Binding Placeholder, Source={x:Reference Control}, Mode=OneWay}">

    </Entry>
</Grid>
```

ValidatableEntry.xaml.cs contains the exposed dependency properties, TextPropery and PlaceholderProperty. The question is: How can I forward the Behaviors property? I tried following, which doesn't work:

```
 public new static readonly BindableProperty BehaviorsProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Behaviors),
            typeof(IList<Behavior>),
            typeof(ValidatableEntry),
            default(IList<Behavior>),
            BindingMode.OneWayToSource);

    public new IList<Behavior> Behaviors
    {
        get { return (IList<Behavior>)this.Entry.GetValue(VisualElement.BehaviorsProperty); }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some code to explain better what you're saying ?

Comment: Yep. This is a good idea. I’ll be back with a condensed snipped.